# nginx upstream relative links do not work

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have configured some upstreams for example:

```
upstream app-explorer-3-tenant-1-env {
    server   10.10.12.16:32708;
}

upstream app-explorer-3-tenant-2-env {
    server   10.10.12.17:31708;
}
```

The following location script will find the correct upstream

```
location ~ /app/explorer/([0-9]+)/([a-z-0-9]+)/ {
        proxy_pass        http://app-explorer-\$1-\$2/;
}
```

So if i access something like this:

http://example.net/app/explorer/3/tenant-1-env

This correctly routes to the first upstream.

The issue is when the site is loaded, I have relative URLS within there that will not work like

```
/type?type=someType
/query
/home
```

Clicking on these links will resolve to

```
http://example.net/type?type=someType
http://example.net/query
http://example.net/home
```

Can anyone advise what I need to do to get the relative links to work? I think some url rewrites are required but I am not sure what.
Note, http://example.net/app/explorer/3/tenant-1-env/query, http://example.net/app/explorer/3/tenant-1-env/home etc does not work either if I manually edit the urls in the browser.

Note the back end servers would normally be serving this from

```
http://10.10.12.16:32708/type?type=someType
http://10.10.12.16:32708/home
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is nothing in those URLs that would indicate which upstream they should be sent to. You need to redesign your URL path scheme, and probably fix your application as well.

Comment: I have no control over the application serving those relative links. As a test, I added an upstream and location like this:upstream testing-app {
    server   10.10.14.120:12728;
}
location /testing/ {
    proxy_pass        http://testing-app/;
}

And i could access the the server http://example.net/testing/
And modifying the links manually to http://example.net/testing/query rendered the correct page so not sure why my other example did not work

Comment: In that case, the app developer should have provided guidance on what cookie it sets that you can use to make sessions sticky in your load balancer. Check its documentation or ask them directly.